# Who are these pruned variants in Episode 5 of Loki?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification, loki-2021

In Episode 5 of Loki TV Show, We see the following characters when Loki opens the bunker hatch. Who are they?

> [image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The detailed answer is below but for a quick reference of what we know so far:

[image: The Loki bandit group looking into the hole numbered for reference]

1. <unknown>
2. <unknown>
3. <unknown>
4. Bicycle Loki
5. <unknown>
6. President Loki
7. <unknown>
8. Poky Loki: a play on In-Prison Loki
9. Glamshades Wolfie: Variant L8914
10. <unknown>

---

The group here is led by [President Loki](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/President_Loki), a variant based on Loki from the [Vote Loki](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Vote_Loki_Vol_1_1) comic run.

[image: Loki in a suit for his run to office]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

The rest of the group are all Loki variants too led by President Loki and they are a counter Loki group to the group that our Loki encounters beforehand of Boastful Loki, Classic Loki, Kid Loki and Alligator Loki.

The Loki on the right hand side stood above the rest appears to be Variant L8914 as shown in episode 2:

[image: Loki and the TVA look at various Loki variants they've encountered before, a hologram of Variant L8914 is shown]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

This variant has been revealed in *Marvel Studios: Assembled*, the making of documentary, to be nicknamed Glamshades Wolfie.

We then also have Poky Loki which is the red haired one in a prison outfit and Bicycle Loki which is clearly the one in white with handlebars on his head.

> **Christine Wada:** They all got different nicknames. They were, like, Glamshades Wolfie, which was kinda based originally of, like, sort of a tribal leader. Like a shaman. And we had Poky Loki. It was just another play on In-Prison Loki. Bicycle Loki.
>
> **Tom Hiddleston:** These are bicycle handlebars, which I think is very creative, and you could probably try to make, to recreate at home, if you so choose.
>
> <sub>*Marvel Studios: Assembled*, Season 1 Episode 3, "The Making of Loki"</sub>

From the above we can see that Marvel has given them all names, they're just not all known right now. Presumably when the Art of book drops they'll be in that.

Comment: Note that unlike the first group of Lokis our Loki encounters none of President Loki's group are mentioned in the credits as far as I can see.